# How to Save excel file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, gridview, directory

Previously , I was trying to export gridview value into excel. but with the code given below i am able to export data into excel. but still not able to **Save Automatically** that excel file into a **fixed folder suppose in C:/ drive**. The code which i have written to export into excel is given below.

```
Private Sub ButtonExport_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)   Handles ButtonExport.Click
Dim rowsTotal, colsTotal As Short
Dim I, j, iC As Short
System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
Try
    Dim excelBook As Excel.Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    Dim excelWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet = CType(excelBook.Worksheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)
    xlApp.Visible = True
    rowsTotal = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
    colsTotal = DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
    With excelWorksheet
        .Cells.Select()
        .Cells.Delete()
        For iC = 0 To colsTotal
            .Cells(1, iC + 1).Value = DataGridView1.Columns(iC).HeaderText
        Next
        For I = 0 To rowsTotal - 1
            For j = 0 To colsTotal
                .Cells(I + 2, j + 1).value = DataGrid1.Rows(I).Cells(j).Value
            Next j
        Next I
        .Rows("1:1").Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Rows("1:1").Font.Size = 10
        .Cells.Columns.AutoFit()
        .Cells.Select()
        .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
        .Cells(1, 1).Select()
    End With
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Export Excel Error " & ex.Message)
Finally
    'RELEASE ALLOACTED RESOURCES
    System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default
    xlApp = Nothing
End Try
End Sub
```

can anybody over here please help me out from this problem that how to save that excel file automatically in VB.NET??

Comment: Have you even try to save it ? Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: yes i can save it externally by save as option of excel. but i want to save it automatically after completing the export.

Comment: Yeah so check the link on my first comment.

Comment: i am not getting that code. where to write? Me.FileFormat, Me.SaveAs and Me.Path is showing error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SaveAs method is defined for `Excel.Workbook`

At the end of your `Try`, just before the `Catch`, write :

```
excelBook.SaveAs(<some path here>, etc...)
```

Refers to [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more informations.

And to exit properly **Excel**, write in your `Finally` block at the start :

```
xlApp.Workbooks.Close()
xlApp.Quit()
```

Comment: "Export excel error the file could not be accessed. Try one of the following :

Comment: after completing into export into excel file. i have written below code in the try block.please check it.excelBook.SaveAs("c:/excelfile.xlsx", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlXMLSpreadsheet, AccessMode:=Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange)

Comment: Try `"c:\excelfile.xlsx"`. And change your to `Excel.XlFileFormat.xlXMLSpreadsheet` to `Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel12` if you want an **xlsx**

Comment: now it is saving the file but i am not open the file. showing error that " excel cannot open the file "name.xlsx" because the file format or the file extension is not valid. verify that the file has not been corrupt and that the file extension matches the format of the file"

Comment: Are you using `Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel12` ?

Comment: Maybe just try `excelBook.SaveAs("C:\excelfile.xlsx")`

Comment: "Export excel error this extension can not be used with the selected file type. change the file extension in the file name textbox or select different file type by changing teh save as type.

Comment: Damn ! Sorry ! `Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook` was the good one from the beginning and I ignore it. My fault :/

Comment: thank you so much. now it is working perfectly. can you please help me in one more thing?? i am saving this file into c drive. i want to implement "SAVE AS" option if the filename(excelfile.xlsx) is already exists in "c:\" drive???? how can i impliment this???

Comment: but my code is working perfectly with out "Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook"

Comment: Keep your code without then ! For your **Save As**, use the method [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) to check if the file already exists and then open a form to choose the new path. But this is a new topic and Google has already a lot of answers to this ;)

Comment: so from now you will not help me to solve this problem.:P . Anyways thanx a lot for your help. i will search on google for "save as" option. :)

Comment: I can help you but the best solution to learn is to search by oneself :) Glad I help you ;)

Comment: ok. let me try first. if i wont be able to short it out will ask you surely :)

Comment: i am able to check whether the file name exists or not .but not able to implement save as option if file exists

Comment: If the file exists, you can ask the user if he wants to save as with a [yes/no msgbox](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/vbnet/threads/339922/how-to-respond-to-msgbox-yesno-buttons#post1443692). Then open a [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx) and do your things.

Answer (score 0):

i just used :

```
    Dim oexcel As Object
    Dim obook As Object
    Dim owrite As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

    < your code > 

   owrite.SaveAs("c:\" & foldername)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question but maybe this'll help someone still.
I recently needed to read, parse and write xlsx files. I used the OpenXML SDK with C# for this purpose. MSDN provides some good tutorials on how to do this.
If anyone has questions I can provide my code.
Just one last note...when I "published" the app an installation of the SDK on the client's computer seemed to be required.